# RuntimeError: Input, output and indices must be on the current device

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

My training fails on this line: `outputs = model(**{key: torch.squeeze(value.to(self.training_device), 1) for key, value in inputs.items()})`

I try training https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/layoutlmv2 model with torch.nn.DataParallel(). I use a single node instance with 4 Gpus in AWS Sagemaker. However, when the code gets to the line above it fails with the specified error in the title.

I tried having a look online and the suggestions seem to indicate to move both model and inputs to Gpu, but I think I already do that. Also, I cannot call `inputs = inputs.to(self.training_device)` because inputs is a dictionary: `dict_keys(['input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask', 'bbox', 'labels', 'image'])`

This is my Trainer class:

```
class LanguageModelTrainer(Trainer):
    def __init__(self, *args, class_weights=None, l1_coef=0, **kwargs):
        self.class_weights = class_weights
        self.l1_coef = l1_coef
        self.training_device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
        model.to(self.training_device)

        loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=self.class_weights)
        outputs = model(**{key: torch.squeeze(value.to(self.training_device),
                                              1) for key, value in inputs.items()})
        loss = loss_fn(outputs.logits.view(-1, model.config.num_labels), inputs["labels"].view(-1))

        if self.l1_coef:
            l1_norm = sum(torch.linalg.norm(p.flatten(), 1) for n, p in model.named_parameters() if 'bias' not in n)
            loss += self.l1_coef * l1_norm
        
        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss
```

For DataParallel part I just followed this tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html

Comment: for each involved variable print `var.device` to get a handle on where things are going wrong

Answer (score 1):

In the `compute_loss()` method, the model should be moved to the `self.training_device` before wrapping it with `DataParallel`:

```
def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
    model.to(self.training_device)
    model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
```

Then move the inputs to the same device as the model:

```
    inputs = {key: value.to(self.training_device) for key, value in inputs.items()}
```

Then pass the inputs to the model without calling `torch.squeeze`:

```
    loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=self.class_weights)
    outputs = model(**inputs)
```

And keep the rest of your code unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Your input dictionary has 'bbox' and 'image', which I think is a **tensor** and **non-tensor**. The 'torch.squeeze' function **cannot** be applied to non-tensor inputs.
This could be the issue. If I misunderstood the info, ignore the following.

To resolve the above issue, apply the

> torch.squeeze

function only to the tensor inputs after verifying using

> isinstance(v, torch.Tensor)

to check whether a value is a tensor. Non-tensor inputs should be left unchanged.

Then pass the modified inputs to the model to train/generate the output.

Modified code that moves the inputs to the GPU and squeezes the tensors could be similar to as follows:

```
inputs_gpu = {k: v.to(self.training_device) if isinstance(v, torch.Tensor) else v for k, v in inputs.items()}
inputs_gpu = {k: torch.squeeze(v, 1) if isinstance(v, torch.Tensor) else v for k, v in inputs_gpu.items()}
outputs = model(**inputs_gpu)
```

This modification should allow you to move the tensor inputs to the GPU and apply the squeeze function to them without affecting the non-tensor inputs.